# Is it safe for multiple threads to read from a Lookup<TKey, TElement>?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, data-structures, lookup

Is it safe for multiple threads to read from a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>`?

`Lookup<TKey, TElement>` is immutable, however [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) states:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

Though I shudder to imagine it, I'm wondering if the machine that pumps out MSDN documentation 
 could be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that fun wasn't allowed here.

Comment: Can you imagine a situation where multiple threads could have problems reading an immutable data structure?

Comment: @ChaosPandion Not really, but MSDN says what it says, so whallah I asked a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Absolutely. Something can be externally immutable, but mutate state internally (e.g. for caching) - and in that case, two threads reading via the public API *could* potentially corrupt the internal state.

Comment: @RonnieOverby, picture was cool, but way to big and absolutely unrelated to your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for articulating what I was afraid of about this class. Do you know definitively whether I can point multiple threads to read from this thing? The other answers are just kind of speculative that it's probably safe.

Comment: @RonnieOverby: I don't, no. I *strongly* suspect it's thread-safe, but I wouldn't like to guarantee it. There are other reasons why it may not be thread safe to read, too - such as the memory model giving "stale" reads from some threads.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sounds like a shoddy piece of code if you ask me. :)

Comment: I wonder where you have found the remark about thread-safety because i don't find it in your link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter this question predates their effort to replace all documentation. It and most other classes in the MSDN shared the quote from the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't like to risk that I may have to debug an obscure multithreading related bug 1 year from now, I'm going to assume it's not safe to use this class without manual synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no writing, doing just reading is thread-safe. This is valid in any case.

Your question is in a sense orthogonal to the notion of thread-safety. A write in combination with a write or read is not thread-safe, but multiple reads without writing are thread-safe.

What MSDN says about instance members not being guaranteed to be thread-safe can only be valid in case of non-thread-safe scenarios, which by definition imply a write operation.

Comment: "As long as there is no writing, doing just reading is thread-safe. This is valid in any case." - That's not true. Think about the memory model - it may be possible for a thread to "see" the Lookup before it's able to "see" the data for all entries, for example. It depends on how the memory barriers have been set up.

Comment: I have no idea what that class does internally when I "read" from one of it's members. I trust that I can feel good about concurrent reads from the classes that specifically say in their documentation, "Hey, it's ok to do this!"

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, that is a good point. I guess it depends on your definition of thread-safety, whether or not it includes visibility as a requirement.

Comment: My off the top of my head definition of thread safety: An operation is said to be thread safe when it has been programmed with concurrent access scenarios in mind.

Comment: @Tudor: If you get to see part of the data but not all of it, that doesn't sound terribly "safe" to me...

Comment: @Ronnie Overby: That doesn't say much. You could have concurrent access in mind, but a completely unsafe implementation. :)

Comment: @Tudor - Yes, that's true and I consciously thought of that when I wrote my definition. But, I'd rather sleep at night instead of worrying about whether they got it right when they programmed `ConcurrentDictionary<TK,TV>`, `BlockingCollection<T>`, etc... That's even more to the point of why I don't want to trust that this class is thread safe because they don't even advise that they had concurrency in mind when they programmed it.

Comment: @Ronnie Overby: If you are not constrained to use `Lookup`, consider alternatives that have multiple reader guarantees, like `Dictionary`. From MSDN: `A Dictionary<TKey, TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.` or even `ConcurrentDictionary` to be completely safe.

Comment: Much as I like the idea of hitting M$ for data access that cannot read data that has not been completely written yet, I think it's a bit unfair :)

Comment: @Tudor - Thanks. I'm not constrained to use Lookup. That's what I was getting at with my last comment: It feels much better to use something when the documentation claims its safe.

Comment: @JonSkeet or others, this is an old topic, but can you elaborate on what you mean by, "It may be possible for a thread to 'see' the Lookup before it's able to 'see' the data for all entries, for example. It depends on how the memory barriers have been set up."? My use case is a singleton caching class that uses System.Lazy's default thread-safety to instantiate a single Lookup class for all calling threads. Then each calling thread never writes to the underlying collection or its internal values, only reads. That must be safe, right?

Comment: @JordanRieger: I'd probably need to see the real code to be absolutely sure - but to be honest the actual memory model implemented is rather stronger than what's guaranteed anyway. I suspect you're fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks! Yes, I think I'm fine, particularly because I'm ensuring that the collection that is fed into the Lookup constructor is a List that is fully materialized beforehand by a single thread (via System.Lazy), and not read or written to directly after that.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard disclaimer for <strike>all</strike> most classes as you've probably noticed. Some methods may be thread safe, but "are not guaranteed".

Generally it is safe to read from collection using multiple threads if there are no writers to collection. If you need to update collection at the same time - use appropriate synchronization or built in thread safe collections like [SynchronizedKeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668294.aspx).

Comment: Not all classes have this disclaimer. Check out `Dictionary<TK,TV>`, `BlockingCollection<T>`, or any of the `Concurrentxxxx<T>`. They let you know that some or all interaction with those objects are safe from  multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks. "all" replaced with "most".

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` is immutable, means that you will get the same values for all members. It does not mean that the items stored in it cannot be modified. So the collection is indeed not thread safe. A perfect example would be that most linq is lazy evaluated, and creating the enumerator could involve executing the lazy code. Trying to enumerate in two separate threads could cause the collection to be realized twice producing the wrong result.

**Update:**
Now that the source code is available on https://referencesource.microsoft.com it is confirmed that internal state is set during method calls without regard to multithreading meaning that you could have race conditions and the `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` class is in fact not thread safe.

Comment: `ToLookup` is not lazy and creates an immutable collection. The fact that it's items are not thread-safe is no evidence for the collection to be not thread-safe. Otherwise all collections in the [concurrent namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) were also not thread safe.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it clearly states in the documentation that the `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` is not thread safe as presented in the original question. I was explaining why.

Comment: if you look at the documentation it's not mentioned anymore

Comment: In the new docs, if you look at methods like Skip you will see that it essentially says what my answer says.

Comment: ToLookup isn't lazy though so i don't see how it's related This is not even about the method ToLookup but about its result and it doesn't matter that the items inside the collection can be modified. You can't mutate this collection without creating a new so the collection itself is thread safe, at least "mostly"(read Jon Skeets comments).

Comment: If you go look at referencesource.microsoft.com and look at the source code for `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` you will see that it sets internal state without regard for threading. Thus instances of this class are not thread safe in all cases.

Comment: Once an instance of it is created(what works only via ToLookup since there's no constructor) it's never modified. But yes, i wouldn't guarantee thread safety of lookup under all circumstance either